# Meaning of jquery function (jquery, mytype)

Tags: javascript, jquery

What **$**, **bi** and **undefined** refers here. And what is the use of **Jquery** and **myType**.?

TIA

```
function($, bi, undefined) {

}) (Jquery, myType);
```

Comment: Look up IIFE and module pattern. This is just a way to explicitly define dependencies and create a closed scope.

Comment: You're missing a `(` at the beginning of the code.

Comment: This is an IIFE. It's used to protect the variables that you pass into it. For example, it is possible that code before yours could include a line like `undefined = true`, which would then break any checks for undefined later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$`, `bi`, and `undefined` are all *parameters* to the anonymous function, which is then called with the *arguments* `jQuery` and `myType`. So `$` will get the value of `jQuery`, `bi` will get the value of `myType`, and `undefined` will get the value `undefined` (because no argument was supplied for that parameter). Those identifiers will be in-scope within the function.

Why would someone write this?

- Re `$`: To use `$` instead of `jQuery` within the function, even if jQuery's `noConflict` mode was being used outside the function.
- Re `bi`: To get the value of `myType` as `bi` (for whatever reason, it's not some standard thing).
- Re `undefined`: Paranoia. Specifically, so that within the function the identifier `undefined` really would definitely have the value `undefined`. For historic reasons, `undefined` is a global variable, not an identifier, and it's possible to shadow it by declaring it within a scope and assigning it a value. Sometimes people used patterns like these to avoid worrying that `undefined` may have been shadowed in this way. (Once upon a time you could even redefine it at global scope, but you can't anymore.)

Answer (score 1):

It's a  IIFE and you send the param jQuery and myType to that anonymous `function`.

```
(function($, bi, undefined) {

})(jQuery, myType);
```

For example:

```
var foo = function ($, bi, undefined) {

}
```

and you call

```
foo(jQuery, myType);
```